# Test a subtraction and apply it if the result is greater than zero

Tags: c#

I'm minimalist and I want that my code has as less lines as possible. In every code I write, my goal is to use as much one-lined instructions as possible and avoiding any recurrent code.

Today I'm facing a problem, I'm not able to reduce an instruction even if I'm convinced it's possible.Let's have a look at my instruction :

```
if((level - 2) >= 0)
{
    level -= 2;
}
```

If know I can use a one-lined affectation in the if like that :

```
if((level -= 2) >= 0)
```

But the subtraction while be always applied even if the test is false.

How can I compact this instruction in one line ?

**EDIT**

I can't use ternary operator because I have to keep the if instruction. Basically I have to execute several operations if the test is true, I just simplified my code to post it.

Comment: Less lines doesn't mean clean code.

Comment: Declare a method that does this and call the method.

Comment: ```level += level >= 2 ? -2 : 0;```

Comment: @kleshenki  this is pretty much my answer that i posted earlier. and why not `-=` to save one more character?

Comment: @Adrian's answer below is 'correct', but the whole idea is daft.  If I came across *any* working 'answer' to this in any codebase I'm involved with, I'd likely re-factor it into your original 'bad' example as it is very clear.  Since it's all compiled into IL anyway, I would fully expect the compile to 'un-do' any such 'optimisation' so all it does is pass some confusion into the future;  this is not a 'gift' I would appreciate if I came across it.  Aim for clarity, not brevity.

Comment: I know that less lines doesn't mean clean code, but this code is quite understandable and seems less professional because of the recurring instructions. It's just my opinion, I didn't want my post to become a debate about it

Comment: @Adrian this is not the same, it checks the condition before add/substract, while yours code not. You can use ```-=```, i just posted an idea. But that seems very messy in terms of understanding of code

Comment: The big question here is WHY you want to do that... is there any point at all, specially since, as you commented many times, you DO have a block of instructions inside the `if`?

Comment: @kleshenki no it does exactly the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only subtract when the level is larger or equal to the value you would subtract.

```
if(level >= 2)
{
    level -= 2;
}
```

Write a general function:

```
public static bool TryToSubtract(ref int from, int value)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (from >= value)
    {
        from -= value;
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

and then use that

```
TryToSubtract(ref level, 2);
```

You can then even make further statements based on the outcome:

```
if(TryToSubtract(ref level, 2))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your level was reduced!");
    Console.WriteLine("You loser!");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer my problem but yes it's simplier like this, thanks !

Comment: @M.Ozn See updated answer. Use a function to reduce the logic to a single line

Comment: Yes it's cool, I would have preferred to use a built-in solution but this one suits my needs. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ternary operator like this

```
level -= level - 2 >= 0 ? 2 : 0;
```

or simpler

```
level -= level >= 2 ? 2 : 0;
```

But I don't think that making everything as "short " as possible is the right way to go.

Comment: Yes I know I can use ternary operator but I need to execute several instructions in the if instruction, I have to keep it instead of using ternary operators

Comment: @Bob yes I did it

Answer (score 1):

If you can live without curlies and newlines, then this could be the shortest, and still very readable (IMHO):

```
if (level >= 2) level -= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to keep the curlies to add other instructions in the if bloc !